# How to prove this arcsine identity?

Tags: trigonometry

In the top of [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcsine_distribution) for the arcsine distribution
it states that

$$\frac{2}{\pi} \arcsin(\sqrt{x}) = \frac{\arcsin(2x-1)}{\pi} + \frac{1}{2}$$

Why is this true? I haven't been able to derive this.

Comment: You need to quantify the formula over $x$.

Comment: You have a typo-the $\sqrt \pi$ on the left should be $\sqrt x$

Comment: @RossMillikan, fixed, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (up to domains)...

Let $\theta = \arcsin\sqrt{x}$ and $\varphi = \arcsin(2x-1)$.  Therefore $\sin \theta = \sqrt{x}$ so $\sin^2\theta = x$.  Also $\sin \varphi = 2x-1 =2\sin^2\theta-1=-\cos(2\theta) = \sin(2\theta-\pi/2)$.  Therefore $\varphi = 2\theta - \pi/2$ so $\varphi+\pi/2 = 2\theta$ so
$$
\frac{\varphi}{\pi}+\frac{1}{2} = \frac{2}{\pi}\theta,
$$
which was to be proved.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way:
$$
\frac{2}{\pi} \arcsin(\sqrt{x}) \overset{\text{??}}{=} \frac{\arcsin(2x-1)}{\pi} + \frac{1}{2}
$$

Differentiate both sides:
$$
\frac2\pi\cdot\frac{1/(2\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{1-x}} \overset{\text{??}}{=} \frac1\pi \frac{2}{\sqrt{1-(2x-1)^2}}
$$

These are routinely seen to be equal, so the expressions above them must differ by a constant.  Plugging in $x=0$ then finishes it off.

One could also just use trigonometric identities.  Maybe I'll post more later....

Comment: I am interested in the trigonometric proof